# Add application name to Twitter post when posting via API

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I am using Twitter API for posting. I want to know is there any method for changing the application name on the post. For example, when I post it shows:

> about 1 hour ago from web

It should be converted to:

> about 1 hour ago from myapplication name

Please guide me on this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about Twitter API support.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can change it. But You have to submit an application to Twitter to approve and once it is approved you have to add your application name to the "source" parameter. Check [Twitter api wiki](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/FAQ#HowdoIget%E2%80%9CfromMyApp%E2%80%9DappendedtoupdatessentfrommyAPIapplication) link for more info about source parameter.

Comment: They no longer use the application process. It's OAuth or nothing now.

Answer (score 3):

If you authenticate using [OAuth](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-FAQ) instead of basic authentication, it will show your application name in the source parameter without you having to go through an application process. They have discontinued that process now that OAuth is in place.

Answer (score 1):

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/FAQ#HowdoIget%E2%80%9CfromMyApp%E2%80%9DappendedtoupdatessentfrommyAPIapplication

Answer (score 0):

[Register a new application](http://twitter.com/apps/new) and then you may use OAuth to use on your site/application, and it should be pulled.